# can numpy interpret column of indices like matlab does

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

```
 mat = nan (5,4)

mat =

   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN

fact = rand(5,4)

fact =

    0.3507    0.5870    0.8443    0.4357
    0.9390    0.2077    0.1948    0.3111
    0.8759    0.3012    0.2259    0.9234
    0.5502    0.4709    0.1707    0.4302
    0.6225    0.2305    0.2277    0.1848

cd =

     1
     5
     2
     3
     4

>> mat(cd, : ) = fact

mat =

    0.3507    0.5870    0.8443    0.4357
    0.8759    0.3012    0.2259    0.9234
    0.5502    0.4709    0.1707    0.4302
    0.6225    0.2305    0.2277    0.1848
    0.9390    0.2077    0.1948    0.3111
```

Is there something similar in python or numpy that does what the last line does basically, ie you can enter in a column of indices and it will automatically populate the nan matrix with the corresponding rows instead of iterating through it and doing this row by row manually.

Also notices cd can have more rows than mat and mat would be able to expand accordingly on its own, at least matlab does.

Answer (score 4):

You can do exactly that in python, just use 0-based indexing instead of 1-based:

```
>>> m[cd-1] = fact

>>> m 
array([[ 0.3507,  0.587 ,  0.8443,  0.4357],
       [ 0.8759,  0.3012,  0.2259,  0.9234],
       [ 0.5502,  0.4709,  0.1707,  0.4302],
       [ 0.6225,  0.2305,  0.2277,  0.1848],
       [ 0.939 ,  0.2077,  0.1948,  0.3111]])
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it works pretty much the same:

```
>>> arr = np.empty((5,4))
>>> arr.fill(np.nan)
>>> arr
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,  nan]])
>>> rand = np.random.random((5,4))
>>> rand
array([[ 0.10378825,  0.36936186,  0.65145694,  0.79532325],
       [ 0.69595542,  0.78740795,  0.31969862,  0.81173803],
       [ 0.06674611,  0.99920068,  0.78696773,  0.01768565],
       [ 0.9948402 ,  0.34200073,  0.60993921,  0.13801365],
       [ 0.18503791,  0.39392016,  0.64800295,  0.98816382]])
>>> cd = [0, 4, 1, 2, 3]   # Numpy arrays are 0-indexed.
>>> arr[cd, :] = rand
>>> arr
array([[ 0.10378825,  0.36936186,  0.65145694,  0.79532325],
       [ 0.06674611,  0.99920068,  0.78696773,  0.01768565],
       [ 0.9948402 ,  0.34200073,  0.60993921,  0.13801365],
       [ 0.18503791,  0.39392016,  0.64800295,  0.98816382],
       [ 0.69595542,  0.78740795,  0.31969862,  0.81173803]])
```

Comment: @ali_m -- I guess I should have tested it before I put my foot in my mouth then... Thanks :)